# What happens to Henry's clothes?

Tags: forever

When Henry 'dies' he surfaces in the nearest body of water nude (the writers seem to think being arrested for indecent exposure is funny), but whatever he wears or carries isn't left behind at the scene of the 'death'- where do they go?

Comment: They're converted to energy and used to transport him to the nearest body of water where he is "reborn" in the fashion of all newly born creatures, naked and defenseless. Without a real understanding of the mechanics of his resurrection, we cannot do much more than speculate.